# In C++ Windows Forms, how can I access a "global" collection of data?

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, forms, command-line-interface

Here is what I'm trying to do.

I have an assignment to create a program that will solve for the deformation of a series of n cylinders connected end to end.

I created a windows forms application in which you can specify the number of sections n.

For each member, there are independent variables: Pressure, Length, Cross-sectional area, and Elastic Modulus.

P, L, A, E, respectively.

Using a trackbar, you can select each particular section and modify its values.

My first thought was to create a class called "SECTION" which stores these variables and computes deformation, stress, strain, and other characteristics.

Then, I would created a vector of these SECTIONs that can be dynamically resized to 'n' number of SECTIONs.

However, since CLI doesn't like custom classes, I figured I would just try creating globally-accessible arrays (of type double) and computing it all on the spot.

I figured I would try this by creating a List under the private variables in the "MyForm" class. But:

> "syntax error: missing ; before <"
>   "missing type specifier int assumed"
>   "unexpected token preceding ;"

(Funny, you would think that since most windows programs use some sort of windows form, it would be simple you create an array and use it. Or created a variable, classes, objects, functions, whatever. I don't know how the vast majority of programmers get away with CLI)

Comment: It looks like the compiler doesn't know what type you're trying to use.  You're possibly not including the right header files, or the type is in a namespace?  It may be helpful if you could post the code that is affected.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your statement that "CLI doesn't like custom classes" ?